# Set form values on page load

Tags: django, django-forms

How to populate a form from DB based on the pk? So if the url is http://demo.com/edit-voucher/123456, how do I get the values of voucher entry 123456 into the form?

The form displays, but don't know how to populate it...

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^edit-voucher/(?P<pk>[\d]+)', reports.EditVoucherView.as_view()),
```

**forms.py:**

```
class EditVoucherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vouchers
        fields = ['event_name', 'valid_start', 'valid_end', 'duration']
```

**views.py:**

```
class EditVoucherView(LoginRequiredMixin, GroupRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'edit_voucher.html'
    group_required = u'voucherEdit'
    form_class = EditVoucherForm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) instead of `FormView`:

```
class EditVoucherView(LoginRequiredMixin, GroupRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'edit_voucher.html'
    group_required = u'voucherEdit'
    form_class = EditVoucherForm
    model = Vouchers
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can access the pk of the form in your template as it is in the url. If you use pycharm, try using the debugger to see if the pk value is available in the template.